# Question on Sections of Hyperelliptic Curve

Tags: algebraic-geometry, schemes

I have a question about a step in the proof of Lemma 7.4.8  from Liu's "Algebraic Geometry and Arithmetic Curves" (page 288):

[image]

If we assume that $X$ is hiperelliptic and we have our finite separable map $\pi:X \to \mathbb{P}^1_k$ of degree $2$.

A rational point $y_0$ of $\mathbb{P}^1_k$ defines a Cartier divisor and let $D:= \pi^*y_0 \in Div(X)$ it's pullback under $\pi$.

Denote by $O_X(D)$ the corresponding invertible sheaf to $D$ and the take into account that the author uses the notation $$L(D)=H^0(X,O_X(D))$$.

My question is why under giving setting we have an inclusion

$$H^0(\mathbb{P}^1_k, O_{\mathbb{P}^1_k}(y_0)) \subset H^0(X,O_X(D))$$

as stated in the excerpt?

Comment: If you have a morphism $\pi : X \to Y= \Bbb{P}^1$, for $f([u:v])\in k(u/v)$ rational on $Y$,  then

$\pi^*$ is the unique homomorphism $Div(Y) \to Div(X)$ such that $\pi^*(Div(f)) = Div(f\circ \pi)$. At the unramified points  $\pi^*(p)=\sum_{q \in \pi^{-1}(p)} q$.

If $Div(f) \ge D$ then $Div(f\circ \pi) \ge \pi^* (D)$ so that $f \in L(D) = H^0(Y,O_Y(D)) \iff f\circ \pi \in L(\pi^*(D))=H^0(X,O_X(\pi^* (D)))$

Comment: I meant $\implies$ and it is $\iff$ when the morphism is surjective

Comment: I still not see how your observation that $Div(f\circ \pi) \ge \pi^* (D)$ implies that the map $H^0(Y,O_Y(D)) \to H^0(X,O_X(\pi^*D)), f \mapsto f \circ \pi$ is injective. by the way: does this map you described above exactly the same as that one we obtain using adjunction between $\pi^*$ and $\pi_*$ and then applying global section functor $H^0()$ to canonical $F \to \pi_* \pi^* F$ with $F:=O_X(y_o)$.

Comment: I don't understand what you wrote. It is obvious $f \mapsto f \circ \pi$ is injective for $\pi$ non-constant.

Comment: yes of course, I see now. here non constant = surjective.

Comment: non-contant means locally surjective, so $\pi(X)$ is dense in $Y$. Every morphism to a curve is surjective when $X$ is a smooth projective curve

Comment: ...but this suffice here by sheaf property

Comment: Is the next section looking at the map $\sigma: X-S\to X-S$ exchanging the two $a,b \in \pi^{-1}(q)$ ? How do they deal with the few points where $a=b$ and where $a \in X,b \not \in X$ ?

Comment: additionally: the point that I mentioned above was that the adjunction as described here https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1800779/explicit-unit-counit-of-inverse-image-direct-image-adjunction?rq=1

Comment: would give us canonically a morphism $O_{\Bbb{P}^1}(y_0) \to \pi_* \pi^* O_{\Bbb{P}^1}(y_0)$ and I was curious if in our situation the story could also be solved by showing directly that $O_{\Bbb{P}^1}(y_0) \to \pi_* \pi^* O_{\Bbb{P}^1}(y_0)$ is injective in our case. The morphism is affine and it is a map between invertible sheaves over integral scheme. So injective and $H^0(-)$ is left exact so   $H^0(\mathbb{P}^1, O_{\mathbb{P}^1}(y_0)) \subset H^0(X,O_X(D))$ would also be injective. does it make sense?